# SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword with ON DELETE NO ACTION Foreign Key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Not sure what i'm missing to get this error?

```
  Error starting at line : 95 in command -
    ALTER TABLE Official_Language ADD CONSTRAINT Language_Official_Language_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (language_code)
    REFERENCES Language (language_code)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    NOT DEFERRABLE
    Error report -
    SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
    00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
```

Any help is appreciated :-) Thanks

Comment: Removed the mysql keyword.  You have an Oracle error.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Official_Language ADD CONSTRAINT Language_Official_Language_fk
FOREIGN KEY (language_code)
REFERENCES Language (language_code)
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Possible choices are ON DELETE [CASCADE | SET NULL]
By default (if you omit ON DELETE) it is the same as you have written.

NOT DEFERRABLE is default (you can also omit it)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
ALTER TABLE Official_Language ADD CONSTRAINT Language_Official_Language_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (language_code)
    REFERENCES Language (language_code)
    NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Default is "no action", Oracle does not make any difference on delete/update.

Possible keywords are `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike MySql, Oracle doesn't support `ON DELETE NO ACTION` - the options are:

- (Nothing) (i.e. enforce referential integrity)
- `ON DELETE CASCADE` (i.e. cascading delete)
- `ON DELETE SET NULL` (update keys to null, if permitted by the column nullability)

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm)

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c817c)